# How should I filter large (70+MB) text files of CSVs with multiple filter types

Tags: python, bash

**tl;dr: I want to change column values conditional on matched col entries with 3 different filters in a 600k line csv, how do?**

I have several files of data with over 600,000 lines. They look like this:

```
random.website.com|1000002644|FunGRP_1000009280_OT|5556667777@random.website.com|User|5556667777|main|Y|6557|main||6557|
```

I want to change the value of column 8 `Y/N` to `N` on a match.

I have a list of filters for columns 2 (enterprise) 3 (group) and 6 (phonenumber) stored in newline separated text files like so:

Phone numbers

```
5553690049
5553690050
5553690052
...
```

Enterprises

```
Loud-YPOxXTFF
res-http
1700000004
...
```

Groups

```
FunGRP_1000009280_OT
1300000004_CollabGrp_1
HostedVKL_1300000035_SA
...
```

Right now I have a program in bash that iterates over every entry in the data, extracting the columns I want to filter with awk (which means 1800k awk invocations), then looping thrice over each thing to check, then reading in each filter in a loop, then checking if the filter matches the item. If it does, awk the line (4th awk) to replace the 8th column and stuff it in the output file. If no filter matches the line, then just put the unchanged line in the output file. It's brutally inefficient, but it works. Code is below:

```
filter () {
  while read -r entry || [[ -n "$entry" ]]; do
    phone="$(echo "$entry" | awk -F "|" '{ print $6 }')"
    group="$(echo "$entry" | awk -F "|" '{ print $3 }')"
    enterprise="$(echo "$entry" | awk -F "|" '{ print $2 }')"
    to_test=("$phone" "$group" "$enterprise")
    filters=("$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE" "$GROUP_FILTER_FILE" "$ENTERPRISE_FILTER_FILE")
    count=-1
    matched=""

    for item in "${to_test[@]}"; do
      count=$(( count+1 ))
      if [[ -n "$item" ]] && [[ -f "${filters[$count]}" ]]; then
        while read -r filter || [[ -n "$filter" ]]; do
          if [[ "$item" = "$filter" ]]; then
            echo "$entry" | awk -F "|" 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} $8="N" {print}' >> "$WORKING$OUTPUTFILE"
            matched="true"
            continue 2
          fi
        done < "${filters[$count]}"
      fi
    done

    # If no filter matches, put the original entry in the output
    [[ -z "$matched" ]] && echo "$entry" >> "$WORKING$OUTPUTFILE"
  done < "$WORKING$UNFILTEREDOUTPUTFILE"
}
```

I need this to be **way more efficient** and I feel like doing this in bash is stupid, which is why I tagged python on here. I'm familiar with python.

I already intend to improve it by moving the awk calls outside of the loop to capture each entire column. Something like `PHONENUM_COL=($(awk '{FS = "|"} {print $6}' data.txt))`. Then (assuming they end up the same length) I can instead loop through the length of the array and just match with something like:

```
[[ "PHONE_COL[$COUNT]" = "$filter" | "GROUP_COL[$COUNT]" = "$filter" | "ENTERPRISE_COL[$COUNT]" = "$filter" ]]
```

The original program that I'm updating was written in bash which is why I continued to try to solve this in shell script, but I'm not a wizard at bash so I've started to look into python + pandas to do this since I feel like this should be way easier. Any suggestions, strategies or thoughts would help. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding properly, the `i`th row matches if its phone number, group or enterprise matches the `i`th entry in those files? Not that it matches any entry in any file, right?

Comment: Yes, if any of the filters match one of the 3 respective terms under consideration then that row matches and we switch `$8` to `N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, following would work:

```
awk "
BEGIN {FS = OFS = \"|\"}
FILENAME=="\"$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE\"" {phone[\$0]++; next}
FILENAME=="\"$GROUP_FILTER_FILE\"" {group[\$0]++; next}
FILENAME=="\"$ENTERPRISE_FILTER_FILE\"" {enterprise[\$0]++; next}
FILENAME=="\"$WORKING$UNFILTEREDOUTPUTFILE\"" {
    if (phone[\$6] || group[\$3] || enterprise[\$2]) \$8 = \"N\"
    print
}" "$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE" "$GROUP_FILTER_FILE" "$ENTERPRISE_FILTER_FILE" "$WORKING$UNFILTEREDOUTPUTFILE" > "$WORKING$OUTPUTFILE"
```

I'm afraid your posted example doesn't supply sufficient information
(e.g. the 2nd field of the line `1000002644` does not match with any lines
in the `Enterprises`) and I've made some assumptions.
In case my code doesn't work well, I'd appreciate if you can post
more information to examine my code. BR.

**[Explanations]**
The point is how we can reduce the number of computations. Your original
code repeats scanning the filter file for the keywords over and over in
the main loop, which is redundant and inefficient. We can drastically
reduce the redundancy by making use of `associative arrays` in `awk`.
(Note that the same mechanism is implemented in many languages with
different names: `hash` in `Perl` and `dictionary` in `Python`, etc.)

Let me illustrate with the first line `FunGRP_1000009280_OT` in the
`$GROUP_FILTER_FILE`. By putting a mark on the word with an associative array
by saying `group["FunGRP_1000009280_OT"]++`, we can afterword test if
the word is contained in the list with a minimum cost of computation.

Now let's go back to my code. Just for the purpose to make use of shell
variables as `$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE` etc. I have enclosed the `awk` script
with double quotes, not single quotes. It may not be a standard scheme because
it requires a lot of escapes with backslashes. (I may should have passed
the shell variables via the `-v` option.)

- The `BEGIN` block is executed just once before reading input lines and
  I have assigned `|` to both input and output field separators.
- The remaining codes are executed on each input lines in the files
  specified as command line arguments.
- The pattern `FILENAME=="$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE"` tests if the current
  input file is `$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE` and the following block `{...}`
  is executed if the pattern matches.
- The word(s) in the input line is automatically assigned to the `awk`
  variable `$0`. Then the first line of `$NUMBER_FILTER_FILE` works as
  `phone["5553690049"]++` to put a mark on it as mentioned above.
- The following codes sets each associative arrays based on the contents
  of each files.
- The final line which starts with `FILENAME=="$WORKING$UNFILTEREDOUTPUTFILE"`
  is the main loop to iterate over the csv file. The line is broken down to
  fields separated by `|` and the fields are assigned to `$1`, `$2`, ...
  in order.
- In case the `if (...)` test is true, the 8th field `$8` is set to `"N"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works like a charm. I had to do some reading to understand it since I'm not a great AWKer but I feel like a learned a lot now that I understand how you did it. So worth it both for the solution and the learning, thanks!

Comment: Good to know it is working. I should have explained how it works.
I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python/Pandas version, which should be reasonably fast and is readable.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load all the data
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep="|", names=['site', 'entreprise', 'group', 'mail', 'name', 'phone', 'a', 'yn', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
phones = pd.read_csv('phones.dat', header=None)
entreprises = pd.read_csv('entreprises.dat')
groups = pd.read_csv('groups.dat')

# Define the match function
def match(row):
    return row['phone'] in phones.values or row['entreprise'] in entreprises.values or row['group'] in groups.values

# Update the column with match function
data['yn'] = data.apply(match, axis=1)

# Write output
data.to_csv('output.csv', sep="|", header=False, index=False)
```